# C++ type casting with pointers

Tags: c++, pointers, casting

I come from a background of C# and Java and I can't seem to understand what casting with pointers means in C++.

For example:

```
int x = 1;
char c = *((char*)&x);
```

What does it do? What it is useful for?

Comment: In C++ you should avoid casting. Casting is a way to tell the compiler "no, no, you will think this is wrong but I'm sure I'm right". In C++ though it's always better to make the compiler right all the time. Casting is a way of suppressing compiler errors. So basically it's more constructive to ask about casting for a particular purpose, rather than casting in general. Both of your examples should be avoided in C++ entirely.

Comment: Do you want to know about casting with pointers in general or from your example it may seem the difference between casting to `char *` and `char const *` ?

Comment: I edited the post, now it should be more clear I think.

Comment: Neither of your examples compile, so they are not meaningful.

Comment: after the edit the code can't compile: should be `char c = *((char*)x);`

Comment: I want to know what is no in the variable c for example what it is mean to cast with the symbol *. I'm coming from a background of c# and java so and I don't know if it is only me but I use casting in those languages for converting from double to float and that kind of stuffs.

Comment: @UnTraDe, you at least need to post an example that compiles, but even if you do that it doesn't mean that it is legal C++. Sometimes in C++ you have a pointer to one type, but really you know it's a pointer to another type, so you cast it.

Comment: I edited it and I think now it should compile and explain what is the question more clearly.

Comment: Where did you come across code that casts with *s anyway?

Comment: What your examples do it take the integer value 1, and pretend it's a pointer. Of course it's very unlikely that 1 represents a legal memory address, so any program that used this 'pointer' is very likely to crash quite quickly.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In both your examples you're making mistakes making the code not compile. So I'll assume you're trying to do the following:

```
int x = 1;
char c = *((char*)&x);
```

Depending on your architecture, `c` will now have either the value of the least or the most significant byte of `x`. In this example this would be either 0 or 1 (this can actually be used to detect the byte ordering).

Your second example won't work, cause you're trying to ignore the `const` resulting in an illegal operation/bad cast (this is also called "const correctness").

Edit: Regarding your comment about "what does it mean?":

In expressions:
`&somevariable` will return the address of `somevariable`.
`*somevariable` will assume the contents of `somevariable` are the address of the actual value, which is then returned.

In declarations:
`datatype` is a normal variable/object. This is passed "by value".
`datatype&` is a reference. This works exactly like normal variables in Java/C# and is passed by reference.
`datatype*` is a pointer. This just contains the address where the actual value is located (see above) and is essentially passed by reference as well.

Actual casts work pretty much similar to Java/C#, but pointers are just that: They point to the location of the actual value. While this might confuse you, pointers in C/C++ work pretty much like the standard variables/references used in Java/C#.

Look at this:

```
MyClass x; // object of MyClass
MyClass *x; // pointer to an object of MyClass - the actual value is undefined and trying to access it will most likely result in an access violation (due to reading somewhere random).
MyClass *x = 0; // same as above, but now the default value is defined and you're able to detect whether it's been set (accessing it would essentially be a "null reference exception"; but it's actually a null pointer).
MyClass &x = MyClass(); // creating a new reference pointing to an existing object. This would be Java's "MyClass x = new MyClass();"
```

Answer (score 4):

Casting in C++ works just like casting in Java, no pointers involved.

```
int x = 1;
char c = (char) x; // Lose precision
```

However, what you are doing here:

```
int x = 1;
char *c = (char *)x;
```

is telling the compiler that the value of `x` is the address of a character. It is equivalent to

```
char *c;
c = 1; // Set the address of c to 0x0000000000000001
```

There are very few times you need to do this.

Answer (score 2):

There are two fundamentally different concepts in C++ which are both sometimes referred to as "casting": One is *conversion*, and one is *reinterpretation*.

Conversion creates a new object with the "same value" as an existing object, but of a different type. Here are some examples:

**Example 1: type promotion**

```
// 1a: promote int to double to get the correct type of division

int numerator = rand(), denominator = rand();
double d = double(numerator) / double(denominator);
```

```
// 1b: convert int to double to achieve a particular argument deduction

int n;
template <typename T> void do_numeric_stuff(T x) { /* ... */ }

do_numeric_stuff(double(n));
```

**Example 2: Derived-to-base conversion**

```
struct B { }; struct D : B { };
D x;

D * p = &x;  // pointer to x
B * q = p;   // implicit conversion; may change the value!
```

On the other hand, reinterpretation allows us to treat one variable as though it was another one. About the only correct and useful application for this is *serialization*, in one form or another.

**Example 3: Serialization**

```
std::ofstream file("output.bin");    // output file
char large_buffer[HUGE];             // in-memory buffer

unsigned int n = get_data();

char const * p = reinterpret_cast<char const *>(&n);
file.write(p, p + sizeof n);                         // write the bytes of `n`
std::copy(p, p + sizeof n, large_buffer);            // ditto

std::copy(large_buffer + 17, large_buffer + 17 + sizeof n,
          reinterpret_cast<char *>(&n));   // repopulate `n` from buffer
```

The standard says that it is undefined behaviour to access an object through a pointer that is not of the correct type (also called "type punning"). While it is OK to store an object pointer in, say, a `void*` and then convert it back and use it, it is *not* OK to treat a float as though it was an integer, etc. The *only* acceptable way of accessing one object as though it was another is the one I demonstrated, namely treating an object of type `T` as though it was an array `char[sizeof(T)]` — that is, you are allowed to access the underlying binary representation of every object.

Answer (score 1):

You should avoid c-type casts like (char*) by all means. If you really have to do a type cast have a look at `dynamic_cast`, `static_cast` and `reinterpret_cast`.

But as already stated, you rarely need casting at all.

Have a look here for fruther information:
http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/typecasting/

http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq/static-typing-and-cpp.html

http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq-lite/print-char-or-ptr-as-number.html

Answer (score 1):

I used many time ago that idiom to access HW at specified address, on custom IO board. So for instance to write at PIC (programmable interrupt controller) to reset some flag (fictious code):

```
#define PIC_LOC 0x1000
#define PIC_ENABLE_PORT *((char*)(PIC_LOC+0x10))
#define BIT_ENABLE (1 << 3)

...
PIC_ENABLE_PORT |= BIT_ENABLE;
...
```