# Pointer value seems to be affected by value preceding it

Tags: python, c++, pointers

In my current workflow I am exporting a 3D model along with various information (vertex colors, UV coordinates e.g.) from Blender through Python. This is stored in a binary file which can be read in C++.

Consider the following code:

Python:

```
ar = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4]
with open('model.bin', 'wb') as file:
    file.write(struct.pack('%si' & len(ar), *ar))
```

C++:

```
u32* ar = (u32*) model_bin; //model_bin is already declared externally
for(int i=0; i<5; i++){
    printf("%d\n", ar[i]);
```

}

This works! However, my file contains more than just one list of data. It contains a lot of data of different types. I keep track of this with the help of different pointers at the start of each new "element". I.e.:

```
rgb* vcols = (rgb*) model_bin;
u32* uvco = (u32*) ((char*) vcols + 2*numVcols)
```

Right now, everything checks out, except for the first value of my UV textures. Setting it to 0 in my export script makes my C++ application read it as -566558720.

If I export and read the UV coordinate numbers as shorts however, everything works fine.

But it gets better! When I set the value of my last vcol[] element to 0, I can read the written int just fine! Setting the final vcol to 1 makes the first uvco read out as 65578.

I realize this is very tricky to debug without seeing the actual code and such, but perhaps someone can lend me some insights or suggestions based on this information?

Thanks,

Patrick

EDIT: Accidentally wrote vcols as u16[], whereas it's really an rgb[]. rgb is a typedef'd unsigned short.

Comment: what are the types for u16 and u32?

Comment: Smells like integer overflow. Karmic since you are in stackoverflow :)

Comment: @40two They're uint16_t and uint32_t respectively. =) If it's an overflow though, why aren't I seeing it earlier? Either with earlier vertex colors or on elements before that?

Comment: What is the actual type for model_bin?  Is it a u16 or u32?

Comment: @40two Oops, in reality vcols is n rgb[], with rgb being a typedef'd unsigned short. I edited my original question just in case it matters.

Comment: Also, what if you removed the casts?  What errors do you get?  More to the point, why are you casting?  Is it to "shut the compiler up"?  If so, then doing that is risky business.  If the compiler is telling you that the types are incompatible, then accept any weird behavior that might occur when you're using C-style casts.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie I shortened my example a bit; vcols is the 8th element in the list. The original model_bin is a const extern u8*. Here is the full "stack": http://www.pasteall.org/51026/c

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie The casts are there because not all elements are of the same type. For example, the first few values are simple unsigned shorts to denote amounts, later I store all kinds of data in different formats.

Comment: @Senshi - Then if the type is really a u8, casting it to some other type does not convert it to that type.  All you're doing is telling the compiler to quit complaining.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie I'm not sure I understand correctly? I do write out the file elements in their appropriate sizes. What this creates is a continuous stream of data from different types. So for example, bytes 1-6 can be unsigned shorts, bytes X-Y can be 32-bit ints. In order to read these back out correctly I need the cast, no?

Comment: @Senshi, well if it were straightforward, you wouldn't be having any issues.  Again, the compiler did emit an error if you didn't cast, right?  So what was the error that the compiler gave you?  You can't just "cast the error away" so easily.

Comment: Please see here:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11708640/c-type-casting-with-pointers

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie If I don't cast to the appropriate type, yes I will get a dozen errors, because I can't just throw an u8* pointer into functions that require u16*s for example. Imagine I start my stream with 2 u8s, followed by some u16s. After casting I can call my u16* by index, like myU16Ptr[2]. Without cast I wouldn't be able to do that, or even read a single value correctly. However, from the starting point of each pointer, the data is guaranteed (by my spec) to be of that type. I'm sure we're talking about the same thing here tbh.

Comment: `because I can't just throw an u8* pointer into functions that require u16*s for example`  Exactly my point.  What makes you think the compiler will like the type punning?  *Don't ignore those errors.* The very fact that you're asking why things are not working indicates that casting didn't work the way you thought it would work.  The link I gave you talks about the difference between interpretation and conversion.   Here is another link talking about breaking the strict-aliasing rule in C++.  http://cellperformance.beyond3d.com/articles/2006/06/understanding-strict-aliasing.html

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie The only reason I'm casting is because the data from that point onward will be in that casted type. So if bytes 1 and 2 are an int32, I will cast it to and read it as an int32. If byte 3 is then a short, I will cast the pointer (+ a 8-byte offset) to a short. I really can't see why this is a bad thing? How would you do this for example?

Comment: @Senshi - see my answer as an alternative to the pointer casting.  One thing -- this doesn't look right: `memcpy(numActionFrames, (u16*) ((char*) bin + 6), 1*numActions);`  Are you sure the last parameter is correct?  I would have expected `numActions*sizeof(u16)`.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie Whoops, I did make a mistake there! numActions was supposed to be a u8. =)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out there was an error with my data alignment. After being pointed to the idea I checked the pointer address and it was not divisable by 4 as it should be. Adding padding has fixed the issue.

Answer (score 0):

I would need to debug your code to find out why you're overwriting other parts of memory, but I won't be shocked if it's due to punning.

As an alternative to all of the casting, you can memcpy() the data to the requisite variable.

```
u32 ar;
memcpy(&ur, model_bin, sizeof(u32));
```

The pointer casting should make you nervous, given the links that I posted in my comments.  Using memcpy() is safer, and you don't get all of those compiler warnings and errors.

Comment: I'm afraid memcpy() isn't really an option though, as I don't want the binary data in memory; I only have 4MB to use in total. =/